# How to use common masters in other project without copy paste of code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have created 5 masters data entry forms in one project. I want to reuse these masters in other project. these two projects are not related to each other. How can I avoid this redundant work in ASP.NET?

Can I create one project for master creation which can be used by few other projects?

Answer (score 0):

Create a project containig the masters and the relevant code and then compile it into a dll that will be referenced by other solutions.